# GWT generate class methods

Tags: java, class, gwt, interface, generator

In my project I have a series of Models which basically just contain data, and have getters and setters for that data (which has to match an API). I am trying to use GWT generators to generate the getters and setters (because they have some logic in them for setting default values and I don't want to have this typed out all the time.

For example, MyBusinessModel.java:

```
public class MyBusinessModel extends AbstractBusinessModel {
    private Integer uid;
    private String name;
    //... and so on
}
```

I then create a `public abstract class AbstractBusinessModel` which has some implemented base methods. I had created a generator for this, `AbstractBusinessModelGenerator extends Generator`, which automatically creates all the getters and setters, but I keep getting errors about `MyBusinessModel` not being able to be a superinterface of `MyBusinessModelImpl` (the generated class) because it's not an interface.

Is there a way for me to generate classes like this (I can't make `MyBusinessModel` an interface because I need it to have private properties), or can I only generate interfaces (which become classes)?

Comment: Could it be that you simply used `implements MyBusinessModel` instead of `extends MyBusinessModel` in the class you generate?

Comment: I've worked out that this is the problem, but the reason for this is that `ClassSourceFileComposerFactory` has the method `addImplementedInterface` but has no way (that I can see) of extending my class, instead of "implementing" it.

Comment: Oh I am an idiot, possibly. I'm going to try with `setSuperClass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use `setSuperClass` on the `ClassSourceFileComposerFactory` instead of `addImplementedInterface`. I didn't realise that this existed. Now I do.